# Getting Opencv not found error even when installed it in conda env

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, deep-learning, computer-vision, yolo

I have installed opencv2 in a conda environment for using with yolo. But i am getting the following error.

Error:

> No package 'opencv' found ./src/image_opencv.cpp:5:10: fatal error:
>   opencv2/opencv.hpp: No such file or directory  #include
>   "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
>             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ compilation terminated. Makefile:86: recipe for target 'obj/image_opencv.o' failed make: ***
>   [obj/image_opencv.o] Error 1

But i was able to access opencv in a jupyter notebook.

Q.2) Can we use opencv3 with yolo?

Answer (score 2):

You can use OpenCV 3 with YOLO. But, in order to run opencv in Darknet framework and train your yolo model, you need OpenCV that is built with **C++ support**, not python.

All of darknet source code is written in C, that's why you need opencv that works with C++ program. Probably you installed opencv in conda environment that works for Python. To check whether you have opencv installed for C++, input this command :

```
pkg-config --modversion opencv
```

If nothing is shown or error, then you need to re-install opencv. Follow this guide to install opencv that works with both Python and C++ : https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv-3-4-4-on-ubuntu-16-04/